# How to open a file with chinese name in python

Tags: python

I am trying to open a file in "w" mode with "open()" function in python.

The filename is : 仿宋人笔意.jpg.

The open function fails with this filename but succeeds with normal files.

How can I open a file with names which are not in English in python?

My code is as follows:

```
try:
    filename = urllib.quote(filename.encode('utf-8'))
    destination = open(filename, 'w')
    yield("<br>Obtained the file reference")
except:
    yield("<br>Error while opening the file")
```

I always get "Error while opening the file" for non-english filenames.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried codecs.open()?

Comment: @Robus: No i haven't tried codecs.open(). Any idea how to use it. I can google, but if you can answer then it would save me time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried modifying my code and rewrote it as:

```
    destination = open(filename.encode("utf-8"), 'wb+')
    try:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
        destination.close()
    except os.error:
        yield( "Error in Writing the File ",f.name)
```

And it solved my error.

Thank you everyone for taking time to answer. I haven't tried the options mentioned above as I was able to fix it, but thanks everybody.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import codecs
f=codecs.open(u'仿宋人笔意.txt','r','utf-8')
print f.read()
f.close()
```

worked just fine here

Comment: But mahendraliya asked about creating a file, not reading an existing one.

Comment: all you have to do is replace r with w

Comment: The encoding parameter of `codecs.open` refers to the encoding of the contents of the file, not the encoding of the filename itself. `utf-8` is irrelevant here since we're talking about an image file anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you're having a problem it seems more likely to do with your operating system or terminal configuration than Python itself; it worked ok for me even without using the codecs module.

Here's a shell log of a test that opened an image file and copied it into a new file with the Chinese name you provided:

```
$ ls
create_file_with_chinese_name.py    some_image.png
$ cat create_file_with_chinese_name.py 
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

chinese_name_file = open(u'仿宋人笔意.png','wb')

image_data = open('some_image.png', 'rb').read()

chinese_name_file.write(image_data)

chinese_name_file.close()
$ python create_file_with_chinese_name.py 
$ ls
create_file_with_chinese_name.py    some_image.png              仿宋人笔意.png
$ diff some_image.png 仿宋人笔意.png 
$
```

Worked for me, the images are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you yield your filename does it look right? I'm not sure if the filname has been mangled before reaching this code segment.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
filename.encode('utf-8')
```

tries to convert filename from `ascii` encoding to `utf-8` and causes the error.