# Is there a function to rename files with python that has no problems with chinese letters

Tags: python, rename

I got a windows system with python running on it and try to rename a folder that has chinese letters in it. But i always get a error message like No such file or directory C:\temp\weight(\xe6\x9c\xba\xe5\x8f\xb0\xe8\xb5\x84\xe6\x96\x99\xef\xbc\x89

```
import os
old_path= r'C:\temp\weight机台资料'
new_path= r'C:\temp\weight'
os.rename(old_path, new_path)
```

```
import shutil
old_path= r'C:\temp\weight机台资料'
new_path= r'C:\temp\weight'
shutil.move(old_path, new_path)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a file with chinese name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336375/how-to-open-a-file-with-chinese-name-in-python)

Comment: You probably do not correctly got the relevant letters. Unsure for Chinese, but some Unicode characters have similar aspect while having different codes. For example 'Α' is the character GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA (U+0391) which is a different character than 'A' which is LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A (U+0041), and still different is 'А', CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A (U+0410). You should use `os.listdir` to find the exact characters of your file. I thought of this after realizing that your error message is inconsistent with the shown code (parens in the message not present in the code).

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message by **copying and pasting** it from the terminal, and formatting it like code. Please also indicate the Python version and Windows version. Finally, please show the corresponding `os.listdir` results, so we can see for ourselves that the file is there. Sometimes the same-looking text can be written using different Unicode characters; it might be necessary to try something like `[ord(c) for c in old_path]` to see exactly what characters are used.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Chinese writing wouldn't normally use any sort of combining characters, but it could possibly have e.g. hidden characters such as "variation selectors". Some hanzi are also just graphically very similar to each other.

Comment: Post a [mre] with debugging details. What's your Python version?

Comment: @Marco That's an ancient article. Things are different these days. See [PEP 529](https://peps.python.org/pep-0529/).